# Creating Calendar table entries, but process currently is very limiting

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to take info from a few models and generate table entries in the model Calendar. I'd like to perfect this method so that It can be done on any day and will just extend from an entry in the Calendar object that has the future most date. Currently in the view as you can see, it just projects the current objects in the Calendar table, and projects it forward a certain number of days. Which limits me to doing this only on mondays, otherwise it falls out of sync with the TimeSlots table. Also depending on the max_jobs the TimeSlot table entry has I need to create multiple calendar entries... currently it only works with two but I guess I can increase it but the code is very repetative

**Template:**

```
<form action="{% url 'portal:custom_admin' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div style="background-color:red; width:15%;">
        <button name="submit">Project</button>
        DANGER! Only click on mondays, until future projecter can go based off futuremost monday generated into Calendar
    </div>
</form>
```

**View with which I am struggling:**

```
@login_required
def custom_admin(request):
"""
Displays MaxSettings, also
Takes time_slots and create a week of it into the future (only should be done on mondays)
Note:eventually this should be able to generate from the future most entry in the calendar instead of today
"""
max_settings = MaxSettings.objects.filter()
time_slots = TimeSlots.objects.filter()

if request.method != 'POST':
    pass
    # Do nothing
else:
    # Project A week forward
    for slot in time_slots:
        if slot.day.weekday == 'Monday':
            new_entry = Calendar(
                date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=7),
                timeslot_A=slot.timeslot_A,
                timeslot_B=slot.timeslot_B,
                booked=False
            )
            new_entry.save()
        if slot.day.weekday == 'Tuesday':
            new_entry = Calendar(
                date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=8),
                timeslot_A=slot.timeslot_A,
                timeslot_B=slot.timeslot_B,
                booked=False
            )
            new_entry.save()
        if slot.day.weekday == 'Wednesday':
            new_entry = Calendar(
                date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=9),
                timeslot_A=slot.timeslot_A,
                timeslot_B=slot.timeslot_B,
                booked=False
            )
            new_entry.save()
        if slot.day.weekday == 'Thursday':
            new_entry = Calendar(
                date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=10),
                timeslot_A=slot.timeslot_A,
                timeslot_B=slot.timeslot_B,
                booked=False
            )
            new_entry.save()
        if slot.day.weekday == 'Friday':
            new_entry = Calendar(
                date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=11),
                timeslot_A=slot.timeslot_A,
                timeslot_B=slot.timeslot_B,
                booked=False
            )
            new_entry.save()

        if slot.max_jobs == 2:
            if slot.day.weekday == 'Monday':
                new_entry = Calendar(
                    date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=7),
                    timeslot_A=slot.timeslot_A,
                    timeslot_B=slot.timeslot_B,
                    booked=False
                )
                new_entry.save()
            if slot.day.weekday == 'Tuesday':
                new_entry = Calendar(
                    date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=8),
                    timeslot_A=slot.timeslot_A,
                    timeslot_B=slot.timeslot_B,
                    booked=False
                )
                new_entry.save()
            if slot.day.weekday == 'Wednesday':
                new_entry = Calendar(
                    date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=9),
                    timeslot_A=slot.timeslot_A,
                    timeslot_B=slot.timeslot_B,
                    booked=False
                )
                new_entry.save()
            if slot.day.weekday == 'Thursday':
                new_entry = Calendar(
                    date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=10),
                    timeslot_A=slot.timeslot_A,
                    timeslot_B=slot.timeslot_B,
                    booked=False
                )
                new_entry.save()
            if slot.day.weekday == 'Friday':
                new_entry = Calendar(
                    date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=11),
                    timeslot_A=slot.timeslot_A,
                    timeslot_B=slot.timeslot_B,
                    booked=False
                )
                new_entry.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('portal:custom_admin'))

calendar = Calendar.objects.filter().order_by('date')
context = {
    'max_settings': max_settings,
    'calendar': calendar,
}
return render(request, 'portal/custom_admin.html', context)
```

**Here are the relevant models:**

```
class MaxSettings(models.Model):
"""
Everyweek day has its own specified open/close time, time slots along with number of available jobs
"""
MONDAY = 'Monday'
TUESDAY = 'Tuesday'
WEDNESDAY = 'Wednesday'
THURSDAY = 'Thursday'
FRIDAY = 'Friday'
SATURDAY = 'Saturday'
SUNDAY = 'Sunday'
WEEKDAY_CHOICES = (
    (MONDAY, 'monday'),
    (TUESDAY, 'tuesday'),
    (WEDNESDAY, 'wednesday'),
    (THURSDAY, 'thursday'),
    (FRIDAY, 'friday'),
    (SATURDAY, 'saturday'),
    (SUNDAY, 'sunday'),
)
weekday = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=WEEKDAY_CHOICES, )
operating = models.BooleanField()
start_work_time = models.TimeField()
end_work_time = models.TimeField()

def __str__(self):
    """Return a string representation of the model."""
    return self.weekday


class TimeSlots(models.Model):
"""time slots along with number of available jobs for that slot"""
day = models.ForeignKey(MaxSettings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
timeslot_A = models.TimeField()
timeslot_B = models.TimeField()
max_jobs = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    """Return a string representation of the model."""
    return '%s %s %s' % (self.timeslot_A, self.timeslot_B, self.day)


class Calendar(models.Model):
"""
this will get it details from TimeSlots and be generated into the future from the  MaxSettings
"""
date = models.DateField()
timeslot_A = models.TimeField()
timeslot_B = models.TimeField()
booked = models.BooleanField()
```